# Stuck in login loop due to change in Path variable

Tags: environment-variables

The output of `echo path` is:

```
/home/adarsh/Downloads/android-studio/gradle/gradle-3.2/bin:/snap/bin
```

I was trying to add `gradle` to my `path` variable but unknowingly I made some mistake, next time I rebooted my PC I was unable to login. I have tried to export path and many other commands.

I have no prior experience in Ubuntu.

Comment: Can you log in to a TTY (press CTRL+ALT+F1, enter you username and password) and undo the changes you made to whatever file in order to change your PATH variable?

Comment: And how do I undo those changes? I already said i have no prior experiences

Comment: And how do I undo changes ? I already said i have no prior experiences

Comment: Well, how did you *do* the changes? I assume you must have edited a file (maybe `~/.bashrc`) and added a line like `PATH= /home/adarsh/Downloads/android-studio/gradle/gradle-3.2/bin:/snap/bin`. Edit that file again and remove the line.

Comment: Nothing there, i just used nano to read the file, nothing about it there

Comment: Please tell us *what you did* to change the PATH variable instead then. We can't read minds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Press <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>CTL</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> and log in with username and password

Run

```
 export PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games"
```

now you can use `nano` editor.

Check `.bashrc` or `/etc/environment` or `.profile` to see whether you have added any other path assignments. Clear them. Save the file after editing. and then reboot your PC.

To open files that are not in your home directory use `sudo nano filename`

Backspace all changes except `PATH`. Then save it and reboot.

Comment: We are not supposed to post "thanks", but only advice.. but you really saved me a whole night! This deserves a huge thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you are not able to open TTY, open root shell from recovery mode in grub menu after restart. 
Then revert any change made in /etc/environment using Vim or any similar editor.
Works for me!